# Conflicting javascript or too many mouseover events?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clone

Currently, I have layered 4 images on top of a background image. When your mouse hovers over each image, it disappears until the user refreshes. I would like to create 26 clones of an image. Ideally, I could position each image copy and the jquery would autogenerate id names like so (#myid(n)) a.k.a #myid1, #myid2. As I am unable to pull this image cloning off so far, I have to copy and paste each block of code over and over again. However, once I added my sixth image, I encountered performance problems, and my code stopped working.

I have included two codepens. This codepen works with 4 image copies : https://codepen.io/narutofan389/collab/NWGpQWo

This codepen doesn't work with 6 copies: https://codepen.io/narutofan389/collab/MWapQyO

I have heard too many mouseover events can create performance issues. I am not sure if this is what the source of my issues. I am also trying on a separate codepen to test image cloning with separate ids. This is the code so far taken from another stack overflow answer:

html

```
<body>
<div id="sand"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
          var img = "<img src ='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4405662/sandsmaller.png' 
          id='myid"+i+"'/>"; 
          $("body #sand").append(img);
      }

})
```

Again I am trying to generate different ids that I can position individually?

Comment: I'm getting an error on your CodePen `TypeError: audio.play is not a function`. I'm using Firefox

Comment: Yes I don't know how too fix that either I am trying to get audio to work but it only works 50% of the time. If that is an issue I could just get rid of it.

Comment: Nvm I added the same codepen twice they are updated now

Comment: I can't help you on this, but I'd suggest linking anything from SO if you reference it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your cloning snippet is in jQuery, I hope a solution using it is acceptable.

First I had to add a `#sand` container missing from your markup, as it's where the code is appending the images. Also added a `div` wrapper to each image to mirror your codepen (although you might not need it), and added a `sand` class to the images.

Then, instead of adding an event for each element, I used [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so I can attach just one handler to the wrapping element. I'm targeting all images inside the `#sand` container that are [not already hidden](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

And then simplified the css a bit removing redundant rules and moving common properties to the new classes.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  // Create the wrapping div
  var $container = $("<div class='sand" + i + "'>");
  // Create the img
  var $img = $("<img src ='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4405662/sandsmaller.png' class='sand' id='sand" + i + "'/>");
  // Add image to container
  $container.append($img);
  // Add container to the document
  $("body #sand").append($container);
}

// Listen when the mouse hovers an image
$('#sand').on('mouseenter', 'img.sand:not(.hide)', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});

$('#sand').on('animationend', 'img.sand.hide', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
html {
  background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/HWJvtDGx/lockcorrect.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.sand {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90vh;
}

#sand6 {
  top: 0px;
  right: 200px;
}

#sand5 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

#sand4 {
  top: 300px;
  right: 200px;
}

.hide {
  animation: fade 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#sand3 {
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 700px;
}

#sand2 {
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 300px;
}

#sand1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HWJvtDGx/lockcorrect.jpg
" alt="lock">
</div>

<div id="sand">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Although it has allowed me to clone images, thanks so much for that  The performance issues still persist with copies after sand 6 (sand 7,8 etc) I have to mouseover a lot to get those to disappear but sometimes they don't disappear at all. Anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: @JacquelineTsang I don't see any performance issue. Those conflict images... are they overlapping with others? If there are, those higher elements will be receiving the `mouseover` event instead, because they still occuppy space since the animation involves the `opacity` property. If you apply `display: none` at the end of the animation it *should* work as you expect.

Comment: @JacquelineTsang I've updated the answer with the previous suggestion. See if it works better for you.